# Simple jail for user with open-ssh

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

Can I confine my users to their /home/%u directory using simply open-ssh configuration? I did the following from what I found on the Internet
Stopped the server
To the sshd_config file appended the following

```
Match group sftpusers
    ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

started the server

**FYI I have the users added to sftpusers group**

My users can still access entire file structure on my system

Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS with open-ssh installed

Comment: Is this only for sftp, or do they also need shell access?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this on OpenSSH_5.3p1 and it's working:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftponly
         ChrootDirectory %h
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding yes
         ForceCommand internal-sftp
```